# Trouble Plotting Seasonality of 1 Years worth of data recorded hourly for 3 parameters

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm having trouble plotting the seasonality of 3 parameters, that have been recorded hourly, for a period of 1 year located in the data set linked above. Any help? I've tried tips from different posts, but none apply to my specific application. I was trying to do it with just 1 parameter at first without any luck. Adjusting the Frequency number hasn't produced any useful results.

```
#clear variables
rm(list=ls())

## C:/Users/shifu/OneDrive/Desktop/EE481/team2/CaliSeasonality.csv
loadingData = readline(prompt="Enter the location of your data: ")

#Load data
data = read.csv(loadingData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

#Declare variables
powerGeneration = data[,2]

#Frequency = X-axis intervals: 24 = 24 hours, 12 = 12 months, 7 = 7 days, 365 = whole year
powerGenerationTS=ts(powerGeneration,frequency=7)

# Create plots of the a10 data
autoplot(powerGenerationTS)
ggseasonplot(powerGenerationTS)
```

**Data**

https://pastebin.com/cX93G6z7

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: None of your descriptions are clear or specific enough: *having trouble*, *without any luck*, and *any useful results*. What is the problem you are having with current code? Post specific errors and undesired results. If in the graph, don't tell us, show us.